# Failed to upgrade from Magento 2.4.1 to Magento 2.4.3-p1

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, composer, magento-upgrade, composer-update

I'm using magento version 2.4.1 and composer version 1.10.25. i tried to update it to magento 2.4.3-p1 using composer but i always received an error. First i run this command:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3-p1 --no-update
```

then i run

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

but i always got this error:

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|don't install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.3
    - Conclusion: don't install csharpru/vault-php 3.5.3
    - Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.5
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.5
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.2
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|don't install allure-framework/allure-codeception 1.5.2|remove allure-framework/allure-phpunit 1.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|don't install monolog/monolog 2.4.0|keep monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.25.5|install monolog/monolog 1.26.0|install monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.27.0
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|don't install monolog/monolog 2.3.5|keep monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.25.2|install monolog/monolog 1.25.3|install monolog/monolog 1.25.4|install monolog/monolog 1.25.5|install monolog/monolog 1.26.0|install monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.27.0
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|don't install monolog/monolog 2.3.4|keep monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.24.0|install monolog/monolog 1.25.0|install monolog/monolog 1.25.1|install monolog/monolog 1.25.2|install monolog/monolog 1.25.3|install monolog/monolog 1.25.4|install monolog/monolog 1.25.5|install monolog/monolog 1.26.0|install monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.27.0
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|don't install monolog/monolog 2.3.3|keep monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.22.0|install monolog/monolog 1.22.1|install monolog/monolog 1.23.0|install monolog/monolog 1.24.0|install monolog/monolog 1.25.0|install monolog/monolog 1.25.1|install monolog/monolog 1.25.2|install monolog/monolog 1.25.3|install monolog/monolog 1.25.4|install monolog/monolog 1.25.5|install monolog/monolog 1.26.0|install monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.27.0
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|don't install monolog/monolog 2.3.2|keep monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.19.0|install monolog/monolog 1.20.0|install monolog/monolog 1.21.0|install monolog/monolog 1.22.0|install monolog/monolog 1.22.1|install monolog/monolog 1.23.0|install monolog/monolog 1.24.0|install monolog/monolog 1.25.0|install monolog/monolog 1.25.1|install monolog/monolog 1.25.2|install monolog/monolog 1.25.3|install monolog/monolog 1.25.4|install monolog/monolog 1.25.5|install monolog/monolog 1.26.0|install monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.27.0
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|don't install monolog/monolog 2.3.1|keep monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.18.0|install monolog/monolog 1.18.1|install monolog/monolog 1.18.2|install monolog/monolog 1.19.0|install monolog/monolog 1.20.0|install monolog/monolog 1.21.0|install monolog/monolog 1.22.0|install monolog/monolog 1.22.1|install monolog/monolog 1.23.0|install monolog/monolog 1.24.0|install monolog/monolog 1.25.0|install monolog/monolog 1.25.1|install monolog/monolog 1.25.2|install monolog/monolog 1.25.3|install monolog/monolog 1.25.4|install monolog/monolog 1.25.5|install monolog/monolog 1.26.0|install monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.27.0
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 103.0.3-p1|don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.4.1|keep guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.5|install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.5
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|don't install csharpru/vault-php 3.5.3|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.1|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.2|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.3|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|install csharpru/vault-php 3.5.3|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.0|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.1|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.2|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.3|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.8.0
    - Installation request for magento/framework 103.0.3-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[103.0.3-p1].
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|don't install monolog/monolog 2.4.0|keep monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.25.5|install monolog/monolog 1.26.0|install monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.27.0
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|don't install monolog/monolog 2.3.5|keep monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.25.2|install monolog/monolog 1.25.3|install monolog/monolog 1.25.4|install monolog/monolog 1.25.5|install monolog/monolog 1.26.0|install monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.27.0
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|don't install monolog/monolog 2.3.4|keep monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.24.0|install monolog/monolog 1.25.0|install monolog/monolog 1.25.1|install monolog/monolog 1.25.2|install monolog/monolog 1.25.3|install monolog/monolog 1.25.4|install monolog/monolog 1.25.5|install monolog/monolog 1.26.0|install monolog/monolog 1.26.1|install monolog/monolog 1.27.0
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.3-p1].
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|install csharpru/vault-php 3.5.3|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.0|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.1|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.2|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.3|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.8.0
    - Installation request for allure-framework/allure-phpunit ~1.2.0 -> satisfiable by allure-framework/allure-phpunit[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4].
    - Installation request for magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ^3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.3.0, 3.4.0, 3.5.0, 3.5.1, 3.6.0, 3.6.1, 3.7.0, 3.7.1, 3.7.2, 3.7.3, 3.8.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.1
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1 requires klarna/m2-payments 8.3.6 -> satisfiable by klarna/m2-payments[8.3.6].
    - klarna/m2-payments 8.3.6 requires klarna/module-core 6.2.4 -> satisfiable by klarna/module-core[6.2.4].
    - klarna/m2-payments 8.3.6 requires klarna/module-core 6.2.4 -> satisfiable by klarna/module-core[6.2.4].
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.0|don't install klarna/module-core 6.2.4|keep guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.5|install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.5
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.0|don't install klarna/module-core 6.2.4|keep guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.5|install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.5
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1|install csharpru/vault-php 3.5.3|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.0|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.1|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.2|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.7.3|install magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.8.0
```

Comment: Can you please share your composer.json file so I will help you

Answer (score 0):

Follow below step for upgrade Magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.3-p1

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

Take a backup of the composer.json

```
cp composer.json composer.json.bak


sudo rm -rf vendor/*
```

change php version to: php7.4

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1 --no-update

composer update

composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

php bin/magento cache:clean

sudo rm -rf var/cache/* sudo rm -rf var/page_cache/* sudo rm -rf generated/code/*

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

Comment: this is working?

Comment: Yes @roshanRakeshyadav

Answer (score 0):

In composer.json try to change version of 'magento2-functional-testing-framework':

from `magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "3.1.0`

to `magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "3.*`

then `composer update`

Also, one other way for Upgrade as below.

You can downloading the Magento 2.4.3-p1 release as a zip download from the Magento site, and opening up the composer.json file. I then copied the programs in the  "require-dev": section to the composer.json file in my Magento, and then Magento would upgrade.

That it.